# What happens to Repeating Alarms set by an app, when the app is uninstalled?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-pendingintent

Let's say my app sets a repeating alarm (that repeats every day) using the code below:

```
myAlarmMgrObj.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, myPendingIntent);
```

What will happen to this pre-set repeating alarm when the user uninstalls my app? Because I have no handle on uninstall, I have no way of knowing when to cancel it.

I am guessing that because there will no longer be a Broadcast Receiver to receive my PendingIntent, the PendingIntent will not start its lifecycle at all. But does this mean that every day, the broadcast will be sent out anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What will happen to this pre-set repeating alarm when the user uninstalls my app?

It is the OS's responsibility to cancel the alarm.

Comment: Does this mean that I should not consider cancelling my Alarms at all, when the app is uninstalled? I don't want the users to have a bad experience with it even after uninstall :)

Comment: @zeiger: "Does this mean that I should not consider cancelling my Alarms at all, when the app is uninstalled?" -- first, you don't have a choice. Second, even if for some reason the alarms are still going off, that's an OS bug, not in your app. Relax.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have enough information now to accept your original answer.